# Conectar o Serviço de Indisponibilidade de bens (CNIB)

Tags: aplicação-web

Olá estou desenvolvendo um app que se conecta com o web service de Indisponibilidade de bens da CNIB em asp.net mvc c#, alguém tem experiência com a parte de autenticação com token rsa que é usado para login para me dar um exemplo de como se faz ?